.NET unable to make outbound connection (timeout)
On Linux, I've been having a really weird issue lately. This .NET code fails with a timeout. Using .NET 8.0.6
using var client = new HttpClient();
client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
var request = await client.GetStringAsync("https://www.google.com");

I tried moving it to the start of the launch sequence of an ASP.NET app and it fails to connect with a timeout. I tried putting it in a desktop app in a separate solution and it fails to connect. It also fails to connect to a regular non-secured HTTP address. Connection is not denied; it just times out.
It works on the production server, and querying with 'curl' works just fine. It only fails on my development machine, and it used to work just fine.
I'm on Garuda Linux, arch-based. I even tried re-installing the whole system from scratch! I had installed docker around the time I started noticing the problem so docker is NOT installed on this brand new install, nor is dockercontainer configured in the project config.
I'm running out of ideas. What the heck is wrong here?
Setting this before the call does not help either.
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Connectivity is a plain simple fiber optic connection at home, with no special DNS or proxy configuration. I made no firewall configuration since a fresh install.
Using Jetbrains Rider on Garuda Linux.
Help?
EDIT: Create a blank console project and ran wtrace
There is this repeated error; doesn't seem like a big deal, it's while loading .NET assemblies
Loader/ResolutionAttempted error [/#47722/1/59/18/] message: 'Could not locate assembly', stage: FindInLoadContext

From the moment it starts on the request
11:14:08.2429 ConsoleApp1 (47722.47739) Network/SocketInfo info [/#47722/1/59/] (null) (CreateSocket) SafeSocketHandle:17653682(0x3E)
11:14:08.2432 ConsoleApp1 (47722.47739) Network/SocketInfo info [/#47722/1/59/] Socket#35320229 (SetSocketOption) optionLevel:IPv6 optionName:IPv6Only optionValue:0
11:14:08.2434 ConsoleApp1 (47722.47739) Network/SocketInfo info [/#47722/1/59/] Socket#35320229 (SetSocketOption) SetSockOpt returns errorCode:Success
11:14:08.2434 ConsoleApp1 (47722.47739) Network/SocketInfo info [/#47722/1/59/] Socket#35320229 (SetSocketOption) optionLevel:Tcp optionName:NoDelay optionValue:1
11:14:08.2434 ConsoleApp1 (47722.47739) Network/SocketInfo info [/#47722/1/59/] Socket#35320229 (SetSocketOption) SetSockOpt returns errorCode:Success
11:14:08.2437 ConsoleApp1 (47722.47739) Network/SocketConnectedAsyncDns info [/#47722/1/59/] Socket#35320229
11:14:08.2438 ConsoleApp1 (47722.47739) Loader/AssemblyLoadStart info [/#47722/1/59/18/] name: 'System.Net.NameResolution, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a',requested by: 'System.Net.Sockets, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
11:14:08.2439 ConsoleApp1 (47722.47739) Loader/KnownPathProbed info [/#47722/1/59/18/] '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.5/System.Net.NameResolution.dll' source: Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventPipeEventSource, runtime: #0
11:14:08.2439 ConsoleApp1 (47722.47739) Loader/ResolutionAttempted error [/#47722/1/59/18/] message: 'Could not locate assembly', stage: FindInLoadContext
11:14:08.2439 ConsoleApp1 (47722.47739) Loader/ResolutionAttempted info [/#47722/1/59/18/] '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.5/System.Net.NameResolution.dll' stage: ApplicationAssemblies
11:14:08.2439 ConsoleApp1 (47722.47739) Loader/AssemblyLoadFinished info [/#47722/1/59/18/] name: 'System.Net.NameResolution, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a', requested by: 'System.Net.Sockets, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a', duration: 0.088ms
11:14:08.2440 ConsoleApp1 (47722.47739) Loader/DomainModuleLoad info [/#47722/1/59/] '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.5/System.Net.NameResolution.dll' module type: managed
11:14:08.3017 ConsoleApp1 (47722.47741) Loader/AssemblyLoadStart info [/#47722/1/59/19/] name: 'System.Runtime.Intrinsics, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51',requested by: 'System.Net.Primitives, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
Unhandled exception. System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 5 seconds elapsing.

Not seeing anything useful.
This is the exact console app I'm trying in different environments
var website = "https://perdu.com";
Console.WriteLine($"Querying {website}...");
using var client = new HttpClient();
client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
var value = await client.GetStringAsync(website);
Console.WriteLine(value);


Please use a tool like https://github.com/lowleveldesign/dotnet-wtrace to get started.

Added the output of wtrace. Not seeing anything useful.

Created a minimal consola app, published it as self-contained, booted into a clean Garuda via USB, ran the clean app on a clean environment. Same issue. This is looking like a OS-level issue! Reported it there.

tried your code on garuda linux on a simple console app, it works fine. i think it's not a problem of Garuda Linux or .NET 8.0

What else could it be? Considering it fails for me in a Live Boot environment, and works for others. This is the most mysterious bug... If it was a DNS issue, it would affect curl.

Querying to this address also times out: http://142.250.217.68. This discards DNS-related issues.

I installed on clean Fedora, updated to latest version, downgraded .NET to v6, and ran the app in standard debug mode. The issue persists. So we discarded the distro and .NET. Great. Awesome.

I tried on Ubuntu Live Boot: same timeout error. From a Windows Live Boot, timeout again!?? Anything wrong with the code?

The issue has been identified: sunspots.
Due to record solar storms, there has been several electric outages in the area, and also an ISP outage.
Since then (probably), IPv6 isn't functioning as expected. The OS reports IPv6 as available, but it doesn't actually work. Resulting on timeouts on outbound IPv6 connections.
It's not everyday you get to blame your technical issues on solar activity.
